# mount not working properly on Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, mount

I have WinXP box and Cygwin installed on it. There are many network drive mapped on windows. when I execute mount command on windows (which uses the same mount executable as Cygwin) a get list of network mapped drives. But same when I do through Cygwin, I see only C: is mapped.

On Windows command prompt.

```
C:\CodeDance> mount
C:\cygwin\bin on /usr/bin type system (textmode)
C:\cygwin\lib on /usr/lib type system (textmode)
C:\cygwin on / type system (textmode)
c:\Own on /own type system (binmode)
v: on /cygdrive/v type system (binmode)
c: on /cygdrive/c type system (textmode,noumount)
k: on /cygdrive/k type system (textmode,noumount)
l: on /cygdrive/l type system (textmode,noumount)
m: on /cygdrive/m type system (textmode,noumount)
o: on /cygdrive/o type system (textmode,noumount)
x: on /cygdrive/x type system (textmode,noumount)
y: on /cygdrive/y type system (textmode,noumount)
z: on /cygdrive/z type system (textmode,noumount)
```

Cygwin, on bash

```
code@DANCE /cygdrive $ mount
C:\cygwin\bin on /usr/bin type system (textmode)
C:\cygwin\lib on /usr/lib type system (textmode)
C:\cygwin on / type system (textmode)
c:\Own on /own type system (binmode)
v: on /cygdrive/v type system (binmode)
c: on /cygdrive/c type system (textmode,noumount)
```

The /cygdrive/v that shown mounted above is not accessible either.

Comment: How to access the mounted network drive through Cygwin?

Comment: What do you mean by "through Cygwin"? Are you sshing in or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

On windows command prompt, try to get the mount commands you need execute to replicate what you have using:

> `mount -m`

Then execute those command in the bash shell (the parts that are missing).